# Solving Simple Assembly Line Balancing with tuples

Tags: cplex

A disclaimer in the beginning: I am pretty knew into CPLEX (and programming in general)

I have to solve a Simple Assembly Line Balancing Problem with the task to build a product with different working steps with predecessor constraints, which are given by a graph. A cycle time is given and the goal is to assign the different tasks to as few working stations as possible.

I a trying to find a way to use tuples as agency matrixes can get pretty messy with increasing complexity. But I am pretty lost here.

It would be really nice if someone could provide me an idea of a possible model. I could not find a similar problem that I can transform into mine (even-though I am pretty sure there is something here already, but I don't understand them...)

Thanks in advance!

Jannik.

Answer (score 0):

Nice video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoG8tLSa0gE

And examples at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/solving-simple-assembly-line-balancing-problem-cp-philippe-laborie/

And many other scheduling models in CPLEX CPOptimizer documentation